# How do I find the power series for $f(z) = \frac 1 {1-z+z^2}$ about $0$ for $z$ complex?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

How do I find the power series for $$f(z) = \frac 1 {1-z+z^2}$$ about $0$ for $z$ complex ?

I've tried computing the derivatives by find, but it gets quite messy.

Wolfram calculated the power series here:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=f021a5566d8509939615e02a20f267e3

Is there some theorem I could use ?

Comment: about which point?

Comment: You can Taylor-expand it around $0$, or Laurent-expand it at $+\infty$. Neither are "too messy".

Comment: Note $f(z) = \frac{1 + z}{1 + z^3}$. Use the geometric series formula.

Comment: Have you tried Partial fraction decomposition, using the fact that $z^2 - z + 1 = (z+j)(z+j^2)$ where $j = e^{\frac{2i\pi}{3}}$ ?

Comment: (1) long division; (2) partial fractions.  Using both methods, you get an interesting equation by comparing them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1-z+z^2}=\frac{1+z}{1+z^3}=\sum_{k\geq 0}(-1)^k\left(z^{3k}+z^{3k+1}\right).$$